# is it important to have constructor in javascript class?

Tags: javascript

when I remove the constructor from the following class car of the javascript then i get no value why is that can someone please explain.

```js
class Car {
  constructor(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
  }

  age() {
    let date = new Date();
    return date.getFullYear() - this.year;
  }
}

let myCar = new Car("Ford", 2014);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'value' + ' ' + '=' + ' ' +
  myCar.age();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

```js
class Car {
  age() {
    let date = new Date();
    return date.getFullYear() - this.year;
  }
}

let myCar = new Car("Ford", 2014);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'value' + ' ' + '=' + ' ' +
  myCar.age();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Because value does not assign to this.year
in the constructor, you assign this.year = year value and getting in age function

Answer (score 1):

The Constructor is the function that gets called when you do `new Car(...)`, it allows you to initialize variables when the class gets "constructed", which is why you can't get a valid value from `age()` since it needs `this.year` to be initialized and the only way for it to be initialized is by calling the constructor.

the "technical" reason you're getting a NaN from your `age()` function is because without the constructor, you're essentially just doing `number - undefined` which can't be calculated, so you end up with NaN.

Comment: "the only way for it to be initialized is by calling the constructor." they could also very well set it after construction. `car = new Car(); car.year = 1980; ...`

Answer (score 0):

You first have to understand what is a constructor in JavaScript.

According to [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor):

> A constructor enables you to provide any custom initialization that must be done before any other methods can be called on an instantiated object.

Therefore the following code won't work:

```
class Car {
  age() {
    let date = new Date();
    return date.getFullYear() - this.year;
  }
}

let myCar = new Car( "Ford", 2014 );
console.log( myCar.age() );
```

Why? because what exactly is happening to the values `"Ford"` and `2014`? Who is receiving those values? To what they are being assigned? Nothing, right?

As @ZackGabri mentioned, your `myCar.age()` function is essentially doing `number - undefined` because `date.getFullYear()` returns a number (e.g. `2021`) but `this.year` is `undefined`.

However, when you add a constructor:

```
class Car {
  constructor(name, year) {
    this.name = name;
    this.year = year;
  }

  age() {
    let date = new Date();
    return date.getFullYear() - this.year;
  }
}

let myCar = new Car( "Ford", 2014 );
console.log( myCar.age() );
```

You are basically saying whenever we make a real car like `myCar` using the `Car` blueprint, set the `myCar.name` to `name` and `myCar.year` to `year`, where `name` and `year` are arguments provided while creating/instantiating this object.

Now when we run `myCar.age()`, it calls the `age()` method which returns `date.getFullYear() - this.year` where `date.getFullYear()` would be `2021` and `this.year` would be `myCar.year` which is `2014`.

Therefore the returned value would be `2021-2014`, which is `7`.

Answer (score 0):

Brother constructor is used to define default values when a instance is created for that class. it's ok if you not use constructor in the class but keep in mind that it's not the appropriate way.
here's my code of class without constructor

```
class Car {
 age(year) {
    this.year = year;
    let date = new Date();
    return date.getFullYear() - this.year;
  }
}
const myCar = new Car();
  myCar.age(2014);
```